# Airflow - How to override default failure notification method

Tags: airflow

Would someone let me know if there is a way to override default failure notification method.
I am planning to send failure notification to SNS, however this means I will have to change all the existing DAG and add `on_failure_callback` method to it.

I was thinking if there is a way I can override existing notification method such that I don't need to change all the DAG.

or configure global hook for all the dags, such that I don't need to add `on_failure_callback` to all the dags.

Comment: Do you have example, how you used it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Cluster policy](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts.html#cluster-policy) to mutate the task right after the DAG is parsed.

For example, this function could apply a specific queue property when using a specific operator, or enforce a task timeout policy, making sure that no tasks run for more than 48 hours. Here’s an example of what this may look like inside your airflow_local_settings.py:

```py
def policy(task):
    if task.__class__.__name__ == 'HivePartitionSensor':
        task.queue = "sensor_queue"
    if task.timeout > timedelta(hours=48):
        task.timeout = timedelta(hours=48)
```

For Airflow 2.0, this policy should looks:

```py
def task_policy(task):
    if task.__class__.__name__ == 'HivePartitionSensor':
        task.queue = "sensor_queue"
    if task.timeout > timedelta(hours=48):
        task.timeout = timedelta(hours=48)
```

The `policy` function has been renamed to `task_policy`.

In a similar way, you can modify other attributes, e.g. `on_execute_callback`, `on_failure_callback`, `on_success_callback`, `on_retry_callback`.

The airflow_local_settings.py file must be in one of the directories that are in sys.path. The easiest way to take advantage of this is that Airflow [adds the directory `~/airflow/config`](http://apache-airflow-docs.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/docs/apache-airflow/latest/modules_management.html) to sys.path at startup, so you  you need to create an `~/airfow/config/airflow_local_settings.py` file.

Comment: Thanks Mik-laj. Could you please let me know if I should modify the airflow `airflow_local_settings.py` file (i.e. `/usr/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/airflow/config_templates/airflow_local_settings.py`) or create new ? if so, where?

Comment: I added a new paragraph.

Comment: check this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65222049/airflow-custom-policy-is-not-throwing-exception